# gm convert: Postscript delegate failed when converting PDF to TIF

Tags: image-processing, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I have a process that runs nightly, converting pdf files to TIF.  Last night, I received an error on a single page:

```
b'gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" 
  "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" 
  "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw" 
  "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r325x325" 
  "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmsauavy" 
  "--" "/tmp/gmb2uu99" "-c" "quit" 
  (child process quit due to signal 11).
  gm convert: Postscript delegate failed
```

This is running on linux (Amazon Linux 2, but I am able to duplicate it on Ubuntu 20.04)

```
> gm version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.36 20201226 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/

> gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
```

There is lots of disk space available, and other than this one page this process has been working successfully for months.  The following command can reproduce the issue, but again only with this one page:

```
  gm convert -background white -flatten -depth 8 -density 325 infile.pdf  out.tif
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Signal 11 is a crash. The version of Ghostscript you are using is 3 years old, you could try updating. If the problem persists you could open a bug report.

Comment: @KenS: if you want to write this up as an answer, I'll accept it - manually installing the latest version (9.55 as of Oct 2021) fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't do answers any more :-) I'm glad it fixed it for you though.